# makefile for cppunit

Tags: makefile, cppunit

this is my makefile :

```
#Makefile
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-lcppunit
OBJS=Money.o MoneyTest.o

all : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o TestUnitaire

#création des objets 
Money.o: Money.cpp Money.hpp
    $(CC) -c Money.cpp $(CFLAGS)

MoneyTest.o: MoneyTest.cpp Money.hpp MoneyTest.hpp
    $(CC) -c MoneyTest.cpp $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm *.o $(EXEC)
```

when i run this makefile, i get errors like those :

> g++ Money.o MoneyTest.o -o TestUnitaire
>   Money.o: In function `main':
>   Money.cpp:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to`CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)'
>   Money.cpp:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `CppUnit::TextTestRunner::TextTestRunner(CppUnit::Outputter*)'
>   Money.cpp:(.text+0x8c): undefined reference to`CppUnit::TestRunner::addTest(CppUnit::Test*)'
>   Money.cpp:(.text+0x98): undefined reference to `CppUnit::TextTestRunner::result() const'
>   Money.cpp:(.text+0xec): undefined reference to`CppUnit::CompilerOutputter::CompilerOutputter(CppUnit::TestResultCollector*, std::basic_ostream >&, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)'
>   Money.cpp:(.text+0xfc): undefined reference to `CppUnit::TextTestRunner::setOutputter(CppUnit::Outputter*)'
>   Money.cpp:(.text+0x168): undefined reference to`CppUnit::TextTestRunner::run(std::basic_string, std::allocator >, bool, bool, bool)'
>   Money.cpp:(.text+0x1a5): undefined reference to `CppUnit::TextTestRunner::~TextTestRunner()'
>   Money.cpp:(.text+0x233): undefined reference to`CppUnit::TextTestRunner::~TextTestRunner()'

It's seems to be that there no link between my class. What's the trouble ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-lcppunit` flag is not correct in `CFLAGS`, which is where you put C compiler flags.  You are (a) compiling C++ programs, not C programs, and (b) the `-l` flag is a linker flag, not a compiler flag.  Also, the `CC` variable holds the C compiler.  You should use the `CXX` variable for the C++ compiler.  Your makefile should look something like:

```
#Makefile
CXX = g++
LDLIBS = -lcppunit
OBJS = Money.o MoneyTest.o

all : TestUnitaire

TestUnitaire: $(OBJS)
        $(CXX) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

#création des objets
%.o : %.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

Money.o: Money.hpp
MoneyTest.o: Money.hpp MoneyTest.hpp

clean:
        rm *.o $(EXEC)
```